# Avoiding "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log10" when converting FFT data to dBFS

Tags: fft, python, scipy, dbfs, numpy

I've attached some code below that I'm having some issues with.  Basically, I need to write a function to get the dBFS value of a signal at a specified Hz value, at a given channel in a .wav file.  For a number of reasons, I need this to work on both 16 bit integer and 32 bit integer formats.  Since SciPy's `.wav` io module supports 16 bit and 32 bit integer, I'm hoping that I could just convert either to 32bit float first, then perform the FFT and dBFS conversions.  For example, if you have a stereo test file that has a 440 Hz tone on channel zero, the function below would be called by `db_val = check_db_at_freq_channel(test_file, 440, 0)` where `test_file` is just a file path.

I have a test file that was exported as both 16 bit int, and a copy at 32 bit int, when I run this function on the 16 bit file, it's fine, but when I run it on the 32 bit file, I get `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10`.  Obviously, there are 0's being passed to the log10 function to convert to dBFS.  I'm wondering if there is a way I can avoid this?  Why does this only happen to 32 bit int converted to 32 bit float?  Is my method of converting to 32 bit float incorrect?

```
import numpy
import scipy.io.wavfil
import scipy.fftpack

def check_db_at_freq_channel(input_pcm_file, hz, channel):
    data_sample_rate, data_pcm = scipy.io.wavfile.read(input_pcm_file)

    data_len_rounded = round(data_pcm.shape[0] / float(data_sample_rate))

    if data_pcm.dtype == 'int16':
        max = float(2**15)
    elif data_pcm.dtype == 'int32':
        max = float(2**31)
    else:
        raise TypeError('data_pcm.dtype {} != {} or != {}'.format(data_pcm.dtype, 'int16', 'int32'))

    # Convert Integer data to floating point.
    data_pcm = data_pcm.astype(numpy.float32, order='C') / max

    # Check for a Mono Input
    if len(data_pcm.shape) == 1:
        data_pcm = data_pcm[:, None]

    data_fft = scipy.fftpack.fft(data_pcm[:, channel], n=int(data_len_rounded * data_sample_rate))

    # Convert to dBFS
    data_db = 20 * numpy.log10(2 * numpy.abs(data_fft) / float(len(data_pcm)))

    # Get Frequency Bins
    data_freqs = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(data_fft.size, d=(1 / float(data_sample_rate)))

    # Get Index of requested Hz value.
    data_index = numpy.where(data_freqs == data_freqs[(numpy.abs(data_freqs - hz)).argmin()])[0][0]
    return data_db[data_index]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_file = '/path/to/some/file.wav'
    val = check_db_at_freq_channel(test_file, 440, 0)
    print val
```

I'm sure there is more information I could provide, so please let me know if I'm missing some crucial information?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie at Python, so there may be a slick way to do it I don't know about, but I would say your problem is really platform independent.  Which of your test cases fail is not important, what matters is your code has the potential to fail.  I would recommend that you put your dB calculation in a loop with a threshold if statement to determine whether you should take the log or assign a predefined value.

I am also wondering why you have "2 *" inside the log argument.  This simply adds a log(2) to the log value.  You already have "20 *" which is "2 * 10 *" to account for the squaring of the magnitude to calculate power.

Ced

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically speaking, log(0) is undefined. The standard behavior for most computer languages, such as matlab, is to return -inf. Some languages, such as C++ will return -inf and raise a div by zero exception. Given that it's just a warning you could opt to ignore or suppress the warning and move on. Another option is to massage all of the 0 values to a very small positive number.

```
fft_mag = math.abs(fft_data)
fft_mag[fft_mag == 0] = np.finfo(float).eps
```